# Old gen is always 100% > causes 100% CPU Usage

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a Java application running in my production which is basically a Spring Rest MVC Project. What I have observed is that heap usage of my application slowly and slowly increases starting with 10% to max 78%.

When it reaches 78%, CPU usage of my nodes becomes constant 100%. It seems that full GC are running too frequently.

Here is my configuration:

```
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -XX:InitialHeapSize=4294967296 -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=268435456 -XX:+ManagementServer -XX:MaxHeapSize=12884901888 -XX:MaxNewSize=5368709120 -XX:MaxPermSize=1073741824 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0 -XX:NewSize=536870912 -XX:OldPLABSize=16 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=12 -XX:PermSize=536870912 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:SurvivorRatio=16 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC
```

Here is snapshot of Visual GC

[image]

You can see the constant high CPU usage.
These are some of the GC log entries:

```
2017-10-02T08:54:42.768+0530: 163327.650: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-10-02T08:54:42.789+0530: 163327.671: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.021/0.021 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2017-10-02T08:54:42.789+0530: 163327.671: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-10-02T08:54:42.789+0530: 163327.671: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
2017-10-02T08:54:42.790+0530: 163327.672: [GC[YG occupancy: 3025966 K (3466240 K)]2017-10-02T08:54:42.790+0530: 163327.672: [Rescan (parallel) , 6.7814290 secs]2017-10-02T08:54:49.571+0530: 163334.453: [weak refs processing, 0.0000540 secs]2017-10-02T08:54:49.572+0530: 163334.453: [scrub string table, 0.0013940 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 7340030K(7340032K)] 10365996K(10806272K), 6.7830680 secs] [Times: user=26.59 sys=0.48, real=6.79 secs]
2017-10-02T08:54:49.573+0530: 163334.455: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2017-10-02T08:54:53.196+0530: 163338.078: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 3.618/3.623 secs] [Times: user=3.80 sys=0.02, real=3.62 secs]
2017-10-02T08:54:53.196+0530: 163338.078: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2017-10-02T08:54:53.212+0530: 163338.094: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.015/0.015 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2017-10-02T08:54:54.143+0530: 163339.025: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 7340030K(7340032K)] 10382251K(10806272K), 2.1178610 secs] [Times: user=2.12 sys=0.00, real=2.12 secs]
2017-10-02T08:54:56.261+0530: 163341.143: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:00.966+0530: 163345.848: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 4.700/4.705 secs] [Times: user=14.18 sys=0.03, real=4.70 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:00.966+0530: 163345.848: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:00.987+0530: 163345.869: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.020/0.021 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:00.987+0530: 163345.869: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:00.987+0530: 163345.869: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:00.988+0530: 163345.870: [GC[YG occupancy: 3046326 K (3466240 K)]2017-10-02T08:55:00.988+0530: 163345.870: [Rescan (parallel) , 7.3009290 secs]2017-10-02T08:55:08.289+0530: 163353.171: [weak refs processing, 0.0000540 secs]2017-10-02T08:55:08.289+0530: 163353.171: [scrub string table, 0.0013900 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 7340030K(7340032K)] 10386356K(10806272K), 7.3026000 secs] [Times: user=28.62 sys=0.52, real=7.31 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:08.291+0530: 163353.173: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:12.068+0530: 163356.950: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 3.773/3.777 secs] [Times: user=3.96 sys=0.04, real=3.77 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:12.068+0530: 163356.950: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:12.084+0530: 163356.966: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.016/0.016 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:12.140+0530: 163357.021: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 7340030K(7340032K)] 10397770K(10806272K), 2.1250470 secs] [Times: user=2.13 sys=0.00, real=2.13 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:14.265+0530: 163359.147: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:18.472+0530: 163363.354: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 4.202/4.207 secs] [Times: user=12.73 sys=0.03, real=4.21 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:18.472+0530: 163363.354: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:18.498+0530: 163363.380: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.025/0.026 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:18.498+0530: 163363.380: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:18.498+0530: 163363.380: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:18.499+0530: 163363.381: [GC[YG occupancy: 3065834 K (3466240 K)]2017-10-02T08:55:18.499+0530: 163363.381: [Rescan (parallel) , 8.9283020 secs]2017-10-02T08:55:27.427+0530: 163372.309: [weak refs processing, 0.0000510 secs]2017-10-02T08:55:27.427+0530: 163372.309: [scrub string table, 0.0013920 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 7340030K(7340032K)] 10405864K(10806272K), 8.9299040 secs] [Times: user=34.99 sys=0.66, real=8.93 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:27.429+0530: 163372.311: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:31.125+0530: 163376.007: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 3.694/3.696 secs] [Times: user=3.80 sys=0.02, real=3.70 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:31.126+0530: 163376.007: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:31.141+0530: 163376.023: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.015/0.015 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:31.203+0530: 163376.085: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 7340030K(7340032K)] 10409819K(10806272K), 2.1555220 secs] [Times: user=2.16 sys=0.00, real=2.15 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:33.359+0530: 163378.241: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:37.571+0530: 163382.453: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 4.205/4.212 secs] [Times: user=12.66 sys=0.02, real=4.22 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:37.571+0530: 163382.453: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:37.591+0530: 163382.473: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.020/0.020 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:37.591+0530: 163382.473: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:37.591+0530: 163382.473: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:37.592+0530: 163382.474: [GC[YG occupancy: 3071464 K (3466240 K)]2017-10-02T08:55:37.592+0530: 163382.474: [Rescan (parallel) , 7.4793360 secs]2017-10-02T08:55:45.071+0530: 163389.953: [weak refs processing, 0.0000660 secs]2017-10-02T08:55:45.071+0530: 163389.953: [scrub string table, 0.0014980 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 7340030K(7340032K)] 10411494K(10806272K), 7.4810960 secs] [Times: user=29.32 sys=0.55, real=7.48 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:45.073+0530: 163389.955: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:48.759+0530: 163393.641: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 3.685/3.686 secs] [Times: user=3.75 sys=0.00, real=3.68 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:48.759+0530: 163393.641: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:48.774+0530: 163393.656: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.015/0.015 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:50.394+0530: 163395.276: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 7340030K(7340032K)] 10412726K(10806272K), 2.1372650 secs] [Times: user=2.14 sys=0.00, real=2.14 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:52.532+0530: 163397.414: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:57.099+0530: 163401.981: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 4.562/4.567 secs] [Times: user=13.79 sys=0.03, real=4.56 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:57.100+0530: 163401.981: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:57.121+0530: 163402.003: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.021/0.021 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:57.121+0530: 163402.003: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-10-02T08:55:57.121+0530: 163402.003: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
2017-10-02T08:55:57.122+0530: 163402.003: [GC[YG occupancy: 3079753 K (3466240 K)]2017-10-02T08:55:57.122+0530: 163402.003: [Rescan (parallel) , 6.3679960 secs]2017-10-02T08:56:03.490+0530: 163408.371: [weak refs processing, 0.0000530 secs]2017-10-02T08:56:03.490+0530: 163408.372: [scrub string table, 0.0013790 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 7340030K(7340032K)] 10419783K(10806272K), 6.3695720 secs] [Times: user=24.99 sys=0.44, real=6.37 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:03.491+0530: 163408.373: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2017-10-02T08:56:07.238+0530: 163412.120: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 3.743/3.746 secs] [Times: user=3.82 sys=0.01, real=3.74 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:07.238+0530: 163412.120: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2017-10-02T08:56:07.253+0530: 163412.135: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.015/0.015 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:07.305+0530: 163412.187: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 7340030K(7340032K)] 10421003K(10806272K), 2.2521140 secs] [Times: user=2.25 sys=0.00, real=2.25 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:09.557+0530: 163414.439: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-10-02T08:56:13.791+0530: 163418.673: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 4.228/4.234 secs] [Times: user=12.87 sys=0.03, real=4.24 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:13.791+0530: 163418.673: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-10-02T08:56:13.812+0530: 163418.694: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.020/0.021 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:13.812+0530: 163418.694: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-10-02T08:56:13.812+0530: 163418.694: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:13.813+0530: 163418.694: [GC[YG occupancy: 3093202 K (3466240 K)]2017-10-02T08:56:13.813+0530: 163418.695: [Rescan (parallel) , 8.0104730 secs]2017-10-02T08:56:21.823+0530: 163426.705: [weak refs processing, 0.0000520 secs]2017-10-02T08:56:21.823+0530: 163426.705: [scrub string table, 0.0014030 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 7340030K(7340032K)] 10433232K(10806272K), 8.0121360 secs] [Times: user=31.38 sys=0.59, real=8.01 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:21.825+0530: 163426.707: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2017-10-02T08:56:25.577+0530: 163430.458: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 3.746/3.752 secs] [Times: user=3.91 sys=0.02, real=3.75 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:25.577+0530: 163430.459: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2017-10-02T08:56:25.592+0530: 163430.474: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.016/0.016 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:26.334+0530: 163431.216: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 7340030K(7340032K)] 10440089K(10806272K), 2.1770880 secs] [Times: user=2.18 sys=0.00, real=2.18 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:28.511+0530: 163433.393: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-10-02T08:56:33.019+0530: 163437.900: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 4.502/4.507 secs] [Times: user=13.64 sys=0.01, real=4.50 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:33.019+0530: 163437.901: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-10-02T08:56:33.043+0530: 163437.925: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.023/0.024 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:33.043+0530: 163437.925: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-10-02T08:56:33.043+0530: 163437.925: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:33.043+0530: 163437.925: [GC[YG occupancy: 3107362 K (3466240 K)]2017-10-02T08:56:33.043+0530: 163437.925: [Rescan (parallel) , 8.2780770 secs]2017-10-02T08:56:41.322+0530: 163446.203: [weak refs processing, 0.0000520 secs]2017-10-02T08:56:41.322+0530: 163446.204: [scrub string table, 0.0013870 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 7340030K(7340032K)] 10447392K(10806272K), 8.2796480 secs] [Times: user=32.44 sys=0.62, real=8.28 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:41.323+0530: 163446.205: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2017-10-02T08:56:45.033+0530: 163449.915: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 3.705/3.710 secs] [Times: user=3.79 sys=0.01, real=3.71 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:45.034+0530: 163449.915: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2017-10-02T08:56:45.049+0530: 163449.931: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.015/0.015 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
2017-10-02T08:56:45.392+0530: 163450.274: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 7340030K(7340032K)] 10449182K(10806272K), 2.2074740 secs] [Times: user=2.21 sys=0.00, real=2.20 secs]
```

The Full GC log is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/keo4i0ss2m60jlk/gc.log.zip?dl=0

The system is 16 GB machine. I used to run on 8GB machine without any issues. Does it indicate memory leak.

Or is it just that I need to increase the system memory?

Answer (score 1):

> The system is 16 GB machine. I used to run on 8GB machine without any issues. Does it indicate memory leak.

It doesn't necessarily indicate that.  But it doesn't exclude it either.  For example, you might have changed the code or you might be now running a larger "problem".

There is no straight forward, clear-cut evidence that can distinguish a memory leak from "not enough memory"

If you suspect a memory leak, then you should run the application using a memory profiler and try to figure out if the memory is being used as you expect it to be used, or not.

---

> Or is it just that I need to increase the system memory?

Well, if the problem is a memory leak, then that probably doesn't solve it.

---

A third option *may* be to redesign or tune the application to use less memory.  For example, if it is caching stuff in memory then reducing the cache size will reduce the memory occupied.  Or if it is generating large amounts of garbage, then you may be able to reimplement something to reduce that.